# R what does "table" command mean when applying to two vectors

Tags: r

First maybe I didn't understand the concept of table well, if I said something wrong in the question, please correct me.

I have a data frame `sells` that contains some columns, one of them is `Style` and one of them is `TitleCli`

When I do: `levels(sells$TitleCli)` I got

```
" MISS  " " MR  "   " MRS  "  "MISS "   "MR "     "MRS "
```

when I do: `table(sells$TitleCli)` I got

```
 MISS      MR     MRS     MISS      MR     MRS  
     99     186     156      66     140      92
```

when I do: `levels(sells$Style)` I got

```
"Adventure" "Children " "Comedy"    "Drama"     "Horror"    "Musical"   "Sci-Fi"   "Western"
```

when I do: `table(sells$Style)` I got

```
Adventure Children     Comedy     Drama    Horror   Musical    Sci-Fi   Western 
       47       151       214        94        50        28        92        63
```

**here is my issue**

when I do `table(sells$TitleCli, sells$Style)`

I go:

```
          Adventure Children  Comedy Drama Horror Musical Sci-Fi Western
   MISS          13        29     24     9      8       0     10       6
   MR            13        41     43    28     11       2     31      17
   MRS           17        44     35    21     11       1     22       5
  MISS            1         7     23    12      5       6      5       7
  MR              2        18     55    13     11      10     16      15
  MRS             1        12     34    11      4       9      8      13
```

my question is where all these values come from? are they the `count` of the rows that have both the style's value and the title's value?

**and** why the style's values are duplicated?

#### Update

This is the file that contains the `sells` data frame

http://www.filedropper.com/weekpurchases18-25

you can import it to your R workspace by : `sells<-read.table(filelocatoin, header=TRUE, sep="\t")`

Comment: You have leading/lagging spaces for `MISS` and `MR` etc.  So, `" MISS "` is not the same as `"MISS"` or `" MISS"`.  Once you correct that, there will not be duplicates.  One option is `library(stringr); sells$TitleCli <- str_trim(sells$TitleCli)` and then do the `table`.  `table` gets frequency count of each combination of elements from those vectors/columns

Comment: @akrun it seems that your answer is pretty much contains all the information that i asked for. If you prefer type it as an answer and I appreciate your time and help

Comment: @akrun if you want to do as Paolo suggests I can erase my own answer.

Comment: @DominicComtois No, you can just update your answer with `str_trim` or `gsub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the numbers are counts. When using 2 vectors as arguments to `table`, you get a joint distribution. And akrun's pointed out ways to fix the duplicates on the `TitleCli` variable:

```
library(stringr)
sells$TitleCli <- str_trim(sells$TitleCli)
```

Now the call to

```
table(sells$TitleCli, sells$Style)
```

Should show what you need, without duplicates on the TitleCli (credits to akrun for this one!)